# State Management and Ignoring Duplicate Requests to API in .NET UWP C#

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

The Question is simple yet more important to me.

I have created a `Page` called `ProfilePage` and in that Page's `Page_Loaded` event, I've made a request to some API and Populated the result to `Profile` Class.

The problem  is, when I navigate back to `ProfilePage` from some other page, I don't want to request the API again (i.e., I don't want to trigger the `Page_Loaded` event again), and I want the contents of the `ProfilePage` to maintain the state.

I've seen relevant questions on **State Management**, but none of those explains about the above condition.

Here's my `Page_Loaded` snippet:

```
public Profile _profile;

private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // This function will return data as "Profile" Object
    var _profile = await _requestAPI();  
}
```

Here's my `Profile` Object snippet:

```
struct Profile
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public string profilePic;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have other requirements, a simple option is that you could create a static value as a flag in the **ProfilePage**, for example, a boolean. Every time you load the **ProfilePage**, check the boolean value.

A simple sample looks like this:

```
    static Boolean isFirstLoad = true;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isFirstLoad)
        {
            //first load
            isFirstLoad = false;
            // your logic for first load
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok, then what about the state of the page??

Comment: @CosmicPredator If the state you mentioned means the UI controls remain the same, a simple option is to cache your ProfilePage.  Adding `this.NavigationCacheMode =NavigationCacheMode.Required;` into the constructor.

Comment: No, I'm talking about caching the images loaded (for example profile picture)...

Comment: @CosmicPredator For example, you have an `Image` control that loads an picture, it will be cached as well.